# How to differentiate $E[X\vert Y\geq y](1-F(y))$ w.r.t $y$

Tags: derivatives, conditional-expectation

It is known that $$E[X\vert Y\geq y](1-F(y)) = \int_y^\infty E[X\vert Y=t]f(t)dt$$

To take the derivative, I think this is just Leibniz rule, but I don't know how to handle the conditional expectation on the RHS in the integral.

Do I need to write the conditional Expectation as an integral and then take the derivative of the double integral?

I don't see double integrals in the answer though, which is why I am confused. The answer is

$$\frac{d}{dy}E[X\vert Y\geq y] = f(y)\frac{E[X\vert Y\geq y] - E[X\vert Y=y]}{1-F(y)}$$

Also, if I use Leibniz rule I don't get an $E[X\vert Y\geq y ]$ term

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just need to differentiate $\int_y^\infty f(\tau) \,d\tau$:
$$\frac d {dy} \operatorname{E}(X \mid Y \geq y) =
\frac d {dy} \frac
 {\int_y^\infty \operatorname{E}(X \mid Y = \tau) \,f_Y(\tau) \,d\tau}
 {\operatorname{P}(Y \geq y)} = \\
-\operatorname{E}(X \mid Y \geq y) \,\frac
  {\frac d {dy} \operatorname{P}(Y \geq y)}
  {\operatorname{P}(Y \geq y)} +
 \frac
  {\frac d {dy} \int_y^\infty
   \operatorname{E}(X \mid Y = \tau) \,f_Y(\tau) \,d\tau}
  {\operatorname{P}(Y \geq y)} = \\
\operatorname{E}(X \mid Y \geq y) \,\frac {f_Y(y)} {1 - F_Y(y)} -
 \frac {\operatorname{E}(X \mid Y = y)\,f_Y(y)} {1 - F_Y(y)}.$$

Comment: How did you get the first term after the second (=) sign?Is it quotient rule with $-\frac{\int_y^\infty)E(X\vert Y=\tau)f_y(\tau)d\tau \cdot \frac{d}{dy}P(Y\geq y)}{P(Y\geq y)^2} = -E(X\vert Y\geq Y) \frac{\frac{d}{dy}P(Y\geq y)}{P(Y\geq y}$. If so that's cool; I did not realize we can use the definition in the process of taking the derivative of the definition.

Comment: Exactly right; it's just $(u/v)' = -(u/v) (v'/v) + (u'/v)$.